# Percentage of occurrences in a column using groupby in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate, percentage

[enter image description here]

[image: 1]

Suppose I have multiple entries in a column search term, I want to calculate the percentage of occurrence of the brand. I know how to get the count of each brand but can someone suggest a way to get these in percentage?

```
df = df.groupby(["searchterm","brand"]).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Comment: show us your desired output as well ( in text)

Comment: `df.groupby('serchterm')['brand'].value_counts(normalize=True)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang This works !! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
df.groupby('searchterm')['brand'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```